# React Native App Published in Play Store not Visible in all devices

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, release

I recently published an app on Play Store that I developed using React Native.

After Google confirms the app was successfully published, I search for it in my Galaxy S8+ and I see it as expected.

If I try from a Galaxy S8 or Google Pixel for example, it doesn't even appear.

I thought it was related to screen sizes so I added the following in my *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="xxx.yyy">

    <!--for Fabric.io-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <!--because of react-native-qrcode-scanner-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
          android:targetSdkVersion="27"
    />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxx"
        />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Haven't had any luck yet!

**Any Ideas??**

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: Post your entire manifest file.  Also, support-screens isn't needed, true is the default.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for your reply! I just edited the question and added the whole AndroidManifest.xml file content.

Comment: How recently? Sometimes it takes a little while to display, even when it might appear right away on other devices

Comment: @Kai It was released 2 days ago actually.